# Can't query Hive external ORC format table?

Tags: hive, hdfs, orc

My external table which is stored as orc has been created properly but i am not able to query on my table its returning

> "Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   serious problem?"

My create command is

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE 30534_events_orc ( eventId string ,event STRING, entityType STRING, entityId STRING, targetEntityType STRING, targetEntityId STRING, properties STRING, eventTime STRING, creationTime STRING )
STORED AS ORC
LOCATION '/30534_data'
TBLPROPERTIES ("orc.compress"="SNAPPY");
```

Comment: A _CREATE_ command within double quotes, containing double quotes that are not escaped?!? Seriously??

Comment: @vaibhav I don't think you need to put quotes, try without quotes

Comment: No i haven't put these quotes while executing my command . Just for differentiate i put it here.. I have edited my question.

Comment: please send us your query and sample data to work on. thanks.